# Python script to loop through all files text in directory... delete any if that's file has lines start by 1

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a Python script that loops through all text files in a directory and deletes any file that has lines that start with 1.

I tried to do it with python, but I don't know how.

My code:

```
import os
import re
import string

filedir = "C:\Users\Mr The Vinh\Downloads\ver 3.0.2.4\ver 3.0.2.4\baiviet_da_thay_link\test"
t = 0
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(filedir):
    for f in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(root, f)
        text = open(path, 'r')
        delkey = re.search(r'^1',text.read())
        if delkey:
            t = t + 1
            os.remove(path)

print 'We deleted file:', t
```

when i run i saw
Process finished with exit code 0 with no erro code

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a place to *order* a piece of code or a program written for you, but you can get help with what you have tried.

Comment: Look at the **os** module of python

Comment: import os
import re
import string
filedir = 'path'
count = 0;
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(filedir):
    for f in filenames:
        text = open(f,'r')
        for line in text.readline():
            if line =="1":
                os.remove(f)
                count = count +1
            else :
            #cha co gi ca

print "We deleted %d file:" %count

Comment: "delete any if that's file has lines start by 1", but I don't see any `if`s in your code. Take this hint and try to fix your code.

Comment: i post my code at top... When i used that code. I saw nothing.. can you fix it for me

Comment: also as you're using windows, use `r"path"` instead of simple string. Backslashes could create issues.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do see something - an error message. Reading error messages (and posting them to SO, if needed) normally helps a lot. Anyway, check out proper usage of `os.walk`. You are trying to `open()` files by their names, but not by their actual path (e.g. "myfile.txt", but not "C:\path\to\myfile.txt"). To get a path, you need to join root and filenames, e.g. `path = os.path.join(root, f)` Also, you delete `filenames`, which is a list of all file names, not the only one that you have just checked for delete key.

Comment: Please, be attentive. You create `path`, but still try to `open() filename `f`. Also, do you see line "We deleted output..." printed? Do you actually have any files in `filedir`? Do any of them actually start with `1`? Check every detail, and if still not working, describe all you do, all you see and all you expect to see.

Comment: thank you...I checked every detaill. and it still not working.

Comment: How do you run your script? Do you see "We deleted..." line in the output?

Comment: Thank all! I have solution for me... thank again

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should iterate over lines with **for line in text.readlines():** to check starting of line.

import os
import re
import string

filedir = "C:\Users\Mr The Vinh\Downloads\ver 3.0.2.4\ver 3.0.2.4\baiviet_da_thay_link\test"
t = 0
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(filedir):
    for f in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(root, f)
        text = open(path, 'r')
        for line in text.readlines():
            delkey = re.search(r'^1',line)
            if delkey:
               t = t + 1
               os.remove(path)
               break

print 'We deleted file:', t